# Is it possible to restrict a friend from seeing a post but let their friends see it

Tags: facebook

In custom view, it is possible to allow your friends to see a post on you own wall and also allow their friends ( "friend of friends" option ) to see it as well?  If you select this option and then exclude your friend from seeing the post, do their friends still see it, just not the friend you have excluded?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just put them on a restricted list. While it makes sense to propagate who can view what if they are subsequent friends of the restricted profile, Facebook does not function this way.

Comment: Lists like this are also how I do it. For example, when I do not want my friends to see posts made for my relatives, I use a list. However, I'm not sure if it has the "friends of friend" visibility propagation.

Answer (score 0):

**No**, it is not possible to exclude your friend and *at the same time* let their friends see the post.

**If you choose Custom option, your post is not public**, and obviously friends of that excluded friend will not be able to see the post.

A post will be seen by Friends of your friend only if your post meets any of the following criteria:

1. Post should be public.
2. Post should be set visible to Friends of friends (since your excluded friend don't have any activity in your post, this case fails)
3. Post should be set visible to Friends of those tagged.